# PEP-8 for function calls

Tags: python, conventions, pep8, code-conversion

I recently started working with Python/Django and I heard about the PEP 8 conventions. After having read [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) I had a better sense how to 'style' my code but I learned programming with Java and I used to just do whatever I like. Could you suggest how to put my example into PEP-8? much appreciated.

```
result = urllib.urlretrieve(
                            "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar.php?"+
                            urllib.urlencode({
                                            'gravatar_id': hashlib.md5(email).hexdigest(),
                                            'size': srt(size)
                                            })
                            )
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: mhh i thought this is a specific programming problem but im new to this forum so i guess you have your reasons for putting this thread on hold. Anyway i got the answers i was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I also find myself confused whether a question belongs here or in codereview or in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, the latter for me has an almost identical purpose as StackOverflow...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try downloading code style linters such as pep8 (a program which checks your code to see if it matches PEP 8 requirements) or pylint. You can find a more comprehensive list and comparison of Python style checkers here: [What are the comprehensive lint checkers for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5611776/646543)

In fact, there's a pep8 checker available online: http://pep8online.com/

If we run your code through that, it tells you:

```
Code    Line  Column    Text 
E126    2     29        continuation line over-indented for hanging indent
E225    2     70        missing whitespace around operator
E126    4     45        continuation line over-indented for hanging indent
E501    4     80        line too long (90 > 79 characters)
W292    7     30        no newline at end of file
```

The fixed version of your code would look more like this:

```
result = urllib.urlretrieve(
    "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar.php?" +
    urllib.urlencode({
        'gravatar_id': hashlib.md5(email).hexdigest(),
        'size': srt(size)
    })
)
```

In essence, the main PEP 8 violation you had was that you were indenting too much. A single indent is fine -- you don't need to align to the opening paren of the function calls. Python is also insistent that your lines don't go beyond 80 characters, but fixing the over-indentation also fixed that issue.

Comment: Deleted my answer - as you beat me to it and included info. about the checker...

Comment: The only reason I'd use a line break after the opening paren is because the line would otherwise be too long, and then indenting it all the way to its original column doesn't help much...

Answer (score 1):

Use more variables. Not only are lines easier to read, the complete code is easier to understand:

```
base = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar.php"
params = urllib.urlencode({'gravatar_id': hashlib.md5(email).hexdigest(),
                           'size': srt(size)})
url = "{}?{}".format(base, params)
result = urllib.urlretrieve(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be suggested by PEP8, but for readability you could break it up like this:

```
base = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar.php?"
params = urllib.urlencode({'gravatar_id': hashlib.md5(email).hexdigest(),
                           'size': srt(size)})
result = urllib.urlretrieve(base+params)
```

Note that [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/) is a utility for formatting Python code to conform with PEP8. In this case, it transforms your original code to

```
result = urllib.urlretrieve(
    "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar.php?" +
    urllib.urlencode({
    'gravatar_id': hashlib.md5(email).hexdigest(),
    'size': srt(size)
    })
)
```